# How to add and/or remove first number of number in Android

Tags: android, numbers

I have a database that has numbers such as '05' & '5', and there are instances where I need to check if they are the same. I'm trying to normalize them when saving them. Can anyone help me in trying to either remove the '0' or add a '0' so I can get a accurately check if they are same?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can compare the integer values of the both.

```
 Integer.valueOf(05) 
 Integer.valueOf(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the `0` in front of `01,02` from a string, you can use a regular expression `replaceAll()` with the start character `^`

```
string.replaceAll("^0","");
```

For multiple `0`s, you can use `*`:

```
string.replaceAll("^0*","");
```

On the other hand, you can do the following if you want to check if it doesn't contain `0`:

```
    if(!string.contains("0"))
```

Then if you want you can add a `0` before storing into the database:

```
string.replaceAll("^","0")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer.valueOf(String)` method
`Integer.valueOf('05') = 5` and `Integer.valueOf('5') = 5`
then you can check your data using this method:
but if you want to do this in `sqlite` query this is not usefull.
so, before adding them into your db you can do a replace, it's better than adding a zero.

`String number_to_add = string.replaceAll("^0*","");`
and then insert this into your db ;)